# Cod: 401 'message' invalid API key using open weather API

Tags: javascript, html, openweathermap

I am trying to build a weather app and anytime I try to search for a city it shows undefined and humidity and windspeed values do not change. Also I get Cod:401 invalid API key error.

I have tried many ways to see what actually went wrong. But still can't find the answer.

```
 <script>
      const apiKey = "c783c8739883eb8cfbb8e5fb0a959dc5";
      const apiUrl =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=";
      const searchBox = document.querySelector(".search input");
      const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search button");

      async function checkweather(city) {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl + city + `&appid=$(apikey)`);
        var data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        document.querySelector(".city").innerHTML = data.name;
        document.querySelector(".temp").innerHTML =
          Math.round(data.main.temp) + "°c";
        document.querySelector(".humidity").innerHTML =
          data.main.humidity + "%";
        document.querySelector(".windspeed").innerHTML =
          data.wind.speed + "km/h";
      }
      searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        checkweather(searchBox.value);
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: The message is telling you that the API key you're sending is invalid. Have you verified that the request you're sending matches what you think you're sending? The browser developer tools can help with this.

Comment: now delete the key and create a new one

Answer (score 2):

### Correct your template literal syntax

**TL;DR.**. You have `$(apikey)` in your `fetch` method with parentheses (`(` `)` ). Change them to `${apikey}` with curly braces (`{` `}` ).

Javascript template literal syntax goes.

```js
`string text`

`string text line 1
 string text line 2`

`string text ${expression} string text`

tagFunction`string text ${expression} string text`
```

You have used parentheses instead of curly braces, which is syntactically incorrect. Try fixing it first.